# Is there a way to block a merge of a branch in Github if the branch contains unfinished Jira tasks

Tags: git, github, devops, jira, cicd

Let's say for the sake of simplicity that we have a git branch named **develop** that contains the features we are working on

Let's say that we have configured our ci/cd platform so that if a merge happens into the **master** branch a production deployment process is triggered based on the **master** branch content.

Let's say at some point we want to merge develop into master, but before doing so, we need to check that every feature in the **develop** branch is validated by the business before merging it into **master**

But sometimes a reviewer don't pay enough attention and end up missing that in the develop branch there is a feature that is not yet validated by the business and merge the develop into master still, which triggers a deployment in production as explained.

We are using Jira as a task management tool and Github

What i'm looking for as a solution is a way to check automatically that the Jira tasks in the develop branch are validated by the business and that there is no feature within the develop branch that is not yet finished when merging, otherwise the merge of develop into master is blocked.

**How ?**

May be finding a way to connect Github and Jira and check that all the tasks in the develop branch (based in commit messages that contains the tasks number) are DONE in Jira sprint for example.

What solution can I use for this use case ? Should I consider developing my own Github bot or may be a Jira plugin ?

Feel free if you have other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that when a PR is open from dev to master (in this case),
A CI pipeline will be executed and will check the states of all tickets that are related to that specific branch.
You can check that by executing JQL search `type = <issueType> AND development[commits].all > 0` if there are any unfinished issues in results, The PR should not be accepted.